# The largest $n$ for which the equation $a_{n+1}x^2-2x\sqrt{a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+\dots +a^2_{n}+a^2_{n+1}}+(a_{1}+a_{2}+\dots +a_{n}) = 0$ has real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics

> Find the largest positive integer $n$ such that for all real numbers $a_{1},a_{2}, \dots ,a_{n},a_{n+1}$ the equation$$a_{n+1}x^2-2x\sqrt{a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+ \dots +a^2_{n}+a^2_{n+1}}+\left(a_{1}+a_{2}+\dots +a_{n}\right) = 0$$has real roots.

#### My Try

If the given equation has real roots, then its discriminant must be greater than zero. So
\begin{align*}
4\left(a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+\dots +a^2_{n}+a^2_{n+1}\right)-4a_{n+1}\left(a_{1}+a_{2}+\dots +a_{n}\right) & \ge 0\\
\left(a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+\dots +a^2_{n}+a^2_{n+1}\right)-a_{n+1}\left(a_{1}+a_{2}+\dots +a_{n}\right) & \ge 0
\end{align*}

After that how can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Try playing around with the equation. What happens if all $a_k$ are equal? What happens if $a_1 = \ldots = a_n = 0$ and $a_{n + 1} \ne 0$? I'm sure you will find other values that are easy to work with, and that could hint at how a solution has to look like.

Comment: What you need to use is the converse: if $\Delta\geq 0$, then the quadratic equation has real roots.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=a_{n+1}$ then the last inequality is $x^2-xT+S \ge 0$ where $T=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$ and $S=a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots+a_n^2$. This requires its own  discriminant $\Delta=T^2-4s\le 0$. As you try increasing the number of $a_i$'s you see at 4 elements the inequality can be made to work but not after that. Here is how it turns out after a bit of algebra

for $n=1$ we have

$-\Delta=3a_1^2\ge 0$.

for $n=2$ we have

$-\Delta=2(a_1^2+a_2^2)+(a_1-a_2)^2 \ge 0$.

for $n=3$ we have

$-\Delta=1(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)+(a_1-a_2)^2 +(a_2-a_3)^2+(a_3-a_1)^2\ge 0$.

for $n=4$ we have

$-\Delta=0(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+a_4^2) \\ +(a_1-a_2)^2+(a_1-a_3)^2+(a_1-a_4)^2 +(a_2-a_3)^2+(a_2-a_4)^2+(a_3-a_4)^2\ge 0$.

for $n=5$ the inequality does not work for all possible $a_i$'s.  Use the suggestion of @vonbrand, above, of setting all of them equal to say $t$ to see $-\Delta=4(5t^2)-(5t)^2=-5t^2 <0 $ for $t\ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks Maesumi would you like to explain me in detail

Comment: @juantheron I added more detail.